# AJAX : How to write the values of variables from ajax to a 'div' tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have fetched the variables from the php file through Ajax and now I want to write the values to a div tag. But Ajax doesn't seem to be working.

**Here's my script.**

```
<script>
var card_number;
var book_issued;

function here(card_numb) {
    alert("pk!");
    $.ajax({

        url: 'details.php', //This is the current doc
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json', // add json datatype to get json
        data: ({
            card_number: card_numb
        }),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('card_number:' + data.card_number + 'book_issued:' + data.book_isued);
            $('#adiv').html('hello world!');
        }
    });
}
```

For now I am trying to pass 'hello world' string but it ain't working.

**This is my details.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['card_number'])) {
$card_number = $_GET['card_number'];

$query     = "Select * from users where card_number = '" . $card_number . "'";
$query_run = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row_numb  = @mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
if ($row_numb == 0) {
    echo "<div class='bdiv1'>No such number found!</div>";
} else {



    $row   = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
    $book1 = $row['user_name'];



    $arr = array(
        'isued_book' => $book1,
        'card_number' => $card_number
    );
    print_r(json_encode($arr));


}
```

**HTML page card_number1.php**

```
<input type="text" id="lab_card_number" name="lab_card_number" placeholder="Card Number" class="input" maxlength="5">
```

Then again a script tag to send the request to ajax script.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('lab_card_number').onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var card_numb = document.getElementById("lab_card_number").value;
        // alert(card_numb);
        here(card_numb);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: show us your html code. and also console log

Comment: Done.. and it's showing nothing in console.

Comment: have you tried consol.log(data); what comes in that?

Comment: no i haven't tried that

Comment: try that and show us your console output

Comment: I tried console.log(data) now and while running the file I pressed ctrl+shift+J. It is completely blank.

Comment: it means you have error in your php code and you are getting no response from php. look in your php code carefully.

Comment: Ok...Also I have pasted almost complete php code now..can you spot any error?

Comment: first of all it does not look like complete code as it does not have any query in it and posted variables from ajax. so that i can locate what you are upto

Comment: In your ajax call, remove the parentheses around `({card_number: card_numb})`

Comment: Your Javascript seems to be ok, your error shoud be in the php.

Comment: I have made a correction in the question and included complete php file.

Comment: Is your div on the page when it load or is it dinamycally added? Cuse if you cant see hello world in the div its because jquery isnt working as intended.

Comment: I added the text within the div tag and it appears on the screen but it's not getting changed after the action is performed..is there any problem in php file?